# Should we take iPhone 4-sized screenshots for app store submission?

Tags: iphone, iphone-4, ios

So far I haven't been able to find the specifications for the iPhone screenshots we'll submit along with our application. (It's universal, so I'm also taking iPad screenshots.) Can they / should they be of iPhone 4 resolution (640x960 instead of 320x480)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can, and should, be iPhone 4 resolution (640x960). You will be able to see the specifications when you create a new version, and click the "?" under Edit images.